# How to clear a variable/definition

Tags: python

I have some code on Enthought Canopy Free Version. Here it is, I'm trying to make it not repeat the secret function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

def guess_once():
    secret = random.randint(1,10)
    print('i have a number between 1 and 10')
    guess = int(raw_input('guess: '))
    if guess != secret:
        if guess not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):
            if guess < 1:
                print ("Nope, too low")

                guess_once()
            elif guess > 10:
                print ("Nope, too high")

                guess_once()
        print('wrong, my number is ', secret, '.', sep='')

    else:

        print('aight, ya got it boi, my number was',guess, nd='!/n')    



    #this is just to start it like a lazy person
guess_once()
```

It's repeating the `"Wrong my secret was #"` line because the `Secret = randint(1,10)` function runs each time it redirects back to the start, how do I fix this?

Comment: I really don't understand what issue you're trying to describe or why you believe it's so heavily linked to Canopy

Comment: Don't use recursion where a `while` loop will do. You don't want to repeat all of `guess_once`, only the part where you call `raw_input` and check its return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create multiple functions so that you don't have to repeat yourself

pseudo code:

```
def get_user_guess():
   val = int(input("guess (1-10)")
   while val < 1 or val > 10:
      print("bad val")
      val = int(input("guess (1-10)")
   return val

def play_game():
   secret = randint()
   guessed_val = get_user_guess()
   if guess == secret:
     print("smarty pants")
   else:
     print("nope")

play_game()
```